# I want my button to hide and show only the contents of the card I clicked on not without affecting the others

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular-material

[image: .]

From the image, you can see that whatever I add repeats itself depending on how many number of cards I create and the drop down button affects all of them at the same time as you can see all of them are open at the same time. I use angular 7 and angular material for design

Comment: Could you share a stackblitz example of your code? Helping out will be easier when we understand how the data looks like for those cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your cards are an array, this could be something like:

COMPONENT:

```js
class MyComponent {
  data: [{
    label: 'First',
    items: [{name: 'name'}, {name: 'name'}, {name: 'name'}],
    isOpen: false
  }, {
    label: 'Second',
    items: [{name: 'Time'}, {name: 'Time'}, {name: 'Time'}],
    isOpen: false
  }, {
    label: 'Third',
    items: [{name: 'baby'}, {name: 'baby'}, {name: 'baby'}],
    isOpen: false
  }]
}

toggleCard(card) {
  card.isOpen = !card.isOpen;
}
```

```html
  <div class="cards" *ngFor="let card of data">
    <div class="card-header" (click)="toggleCard(card)">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content" *ngIf="card.isOpen">
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now alright now. I guess this is why stackoverflow is important. To help when you get clouded. Thanks again.